# Python: get specific output from nested JSON structure

Tags: python, json

newbie Python-programmer is looking for some help. I'm trying to get specific information from an API into a Panda dataframe. The API provides a JSON-response with several levels.

```
{ 
"schedule" {
   "leagues"{
     "events"{   a="A"
       "markets" { b="B" c="C" d="D" }}
     "events"{ e="E"
       "markets" { f="F" g="G" h="H" }}  etc
```

I would like to create data-frame that consists of entries A - B - D, then E - F - H, then etc and I'm really struggling. I've tried flatten (which flattens the entire response, which isn't what I need), and I've tried json_normalize which I'm having trouble fully grasping. I don't get errors, but I can't seem to get into the third (events) level where there's actual info I need. It's not clear to me how I am able to discard the first two levels from the output, or, when I get there, how I can discard C from the output.  Any advice in a certain direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you please format the example properly? As it is currently, it's not clear if events and markets are on the same level, or are markets part of the events.

Comment: I've made an edit. I hope it's more clear now. Markets are part of events (a level below events). So, events is third-level, markets is fourth-level.